# Eilenberg-Watts Theorem Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-explanation

I am currently reading about the Eilenberg-Watts theorem. I got the original work from Charles Watts "Intrinsic Characterizations of Some Additive Functors" and theorem 1 is what I am interested in.
Alternatively the proof is stated [here](https://specksofmath.wordpress.com/2015/04/26/the-theorems-of-eilenberg-watts-part-1/) and the important part [here in Lemma 1](https://specksofmath.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/eilenberg-watts-prelude/).

The proof in Watts says the following (a few, very small changes are made be me to fit it in my paper):

> Consider a functor $F: \mathrm{mod-}A  \rightarrow \mathrm{mod-}A$, a module $M \in \mathrm{mod-}A$, $m \in M$ and the homomorphism $\phi_m: A \rightarrow M, a \mapsto a\cdot m$.

> Since $\phi_m \in \mathrm{Hom}(A, M)$ we can apply $F$ on $\phi_m$ and get $F(\phi_m): F(A) \rightarrow F(M)$.

> We define
> $$\Psi_0^M: M \times F(A) \rightarrow F(M), (m, \tilde{a})\mapsto F(\phi_m)(\tilde{a}),$$ where $a \in A$ and $\tilde{a} \in F(A)$.

> Since $A$ is a bimodule over itself consider  $\Psi_0^A: A \times F(A)\rightarrow F(A)$ and by that $F(A)$ gets a left module structure. This is compatible with the right module structure such that $F(A)$ is a bimodule.

> By the universal property of the tensor product we get $\Psi^M: M\otimes F(A) \rightarrow F(M)$.

> Next we show that $(\Psi^M)_{M \in \mathrm{mod-}A}$ is a natural transformation [...]

> Since $F$ and $- \otimes F(A)$ commute with direct sums, it follows that $\Psi^M$ is an isomorphism whenever $M$ is a free module.  Now take an arbitrary $N \in \mathrm{mod-}A$.  Look at a chosen exact sequence
> $$ 0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow  M \rightarrow  N \rightarrow 0 $$
> where $M$ is free. Since $F$ and $- \otimes F(A)$ are right-exact, we get the following diagram with exact rows:
> [image]

> With a diagram chase we can conclude that $\Psi^N$ is an epimorphism. Since $N$ was chosen arbitrary it follows that $\Psi^R$ is an epimorphism.  Again with a diagram chase it follows that $\Psi^N$ is a monomorphism and hence an isomorphism.

My questions to that are the following:

- Why is $\Psi^M$ an isomorphism if $M$ is free?
- What is the module $R$?
- Why does such an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ exist?
- Why is $\Psi^R$ an epimorphism since $N$ was chosen arbitrary?

If you want to check the other source (Specksmath) I gave, my questions would be:

- What are $F_0$ and $F_1$?
- Why can we say that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism for both of them?
- Why does such an exact sequence $F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ exist?

Maybe someone can help me understand this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact sequences exist because for any module $N$, we can always take

- $M=F(I)$ to be the free module on some set $I$ of generators of $N$
- $F(I)\to N$ to be the map induced by the inclusion $I\hookrightarrow N$ and the universal property of the free module $F(I)$

and this is a surjective morphism, because $I$ generates $N$. Then if you take $R$ to be the kernel of $M\to N$, with its inclusion into $M$, you have by construction a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow R \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0.$$
This is what happens in the article. You can also apply the same trick to obtain a surjective map $F(J)\to R$, and then composing this with the inclusion $R\hookrightarrow F(I)$ gives you an exact sequence
$$F(J) \rightarrow F(I) \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0,$$
and that's what happens in the blog post (with slightly different notation).

Now in the article, $\Psi^A$ is the canonical isomorphism $A\otimes_A F(A)\to F(A)$, since the structure of left $A$-module of $F(A)$ is exactly the bilinear map that induces $\Psi_A$. Moreover if $M=F(I)=\bigoplus_{i\in I}A$, then since $\_\otimes_AF(A)$ and $F$ commute with direct sums we have canonical isomorphisms
$$\bigoplus_{i\in I}(A\otimes_A F(A))\to M\otimes_A F(A)\quad \text{and}\quad \bigoplus_{i\in I}F(A)\to F(M),$$
which make the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}\bigoplus_{i\in I}(A\otimes_A F(A)) @>>> M\otimes_A F(A)\\
@V{\oplus_i \Psi^{A}}VV @VV{\Psi^M}V \\
\bigoplus_{i\in I}F(A) @>>> F(M)\end{CD}$$
commute. In particular, $\Psi^M$ is then an isomorphism.

This implies that the composite $M\otimes_A F(A)\to F(M)\to F(N)$ is surjective, and then so is $\Psi^N$, thanks to the commutative diagram you've written. This is true for any module $N$; in particular, it's also true for $R$.

Comment: Thanks a lot... A few questions to your notation: In my question, $M$ is the free module and $N$ an arbitrary one. In your answer $M$ ist the arbitrary one in the beginning. Later you say that $M = \oplus A$ is $M$ still the arbitrary module or the free module?

Comment: @P.Schulze I started with notation that matched the blog post and then inadvertently switched to the article, so $M$ was an arbitrary module in the first part and then a free module. I've edited to keep the notation closer to the article.